Как изменить адрес массива в памяти?
Стоит задача, используя только указатели и malloc, выделить память под массив и перезаписать его туда.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int sizeOfArr = 4, quantityOfNumbers = 1;
float arr[1] = {0};
float *pointerNewArr = arr;

pointerNewArr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeOfArr);

for (i = 0; i < quantityOfNumbers; ++i){
    *(pointerNewArr + i) = arr[i];
}

arr = pointerNewArr;

Мой наивный ум думал, что такой код сработает, но как бы не старался, но перезаписать указатель массива на указатель pointerNewArr не получается.

Выделили через malloc, перезаписали (зачем для одного элемента цикл - в упор не понимаю...). Что вам еще надо? Выполнить категорически запрещенную операцию? :)

Если я не ошибаюсь, то тогда я потеряю значения из прошлого массива, чего я не хочу

При копировании данные источника (это откуда пересылали в новое место) не изменяются

Вот как раз если бы ваш способ сработал, вы бы потеряли "значения из прошлого массива", потеряв указатель на них...

arr адрес на стеке. Он задается компилятором и не меняется. pointerNewArr указатель, сначала указывает на arr, потом на новую область в куче. Переменную из стека в кучу не перенести.
Используйте указатели если хочется менять адрес.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int sizeOfArr = 4, quantityOfNumbers = 1;
float stackarr[1] = {0};
float *arr = stackarr;
float *pointerNewArr = arr;

pointerNewArr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeOfArr);

for (i = 0; i < quantityOfNumbers; ++i){
    *(pointerNewArr + i) = arr[i];
}

arr = pointerNewArr;

